# Tropico 3 on Steam - need a activation code?

Tags: steam, tropico-3, drm

I just bought and downloaded Tropico 3 on Steam.  It's now asking me for an activation code.  Is this a bug?  If not where can I find my code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you need a CD Key to validate the game.  You can find the CD Key on the right menu in the Steam Details view of the game.

[image: Tropico 3 CD Key Link]